# bcrypt crashing node_modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, bcrypt

I'm currently building a react native app using typescript and when after running  `npm i bcrypt` `node_modules` crash and says the error below:

`ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html 1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders <!doctype html> | <html> | <head>`

I tried removing `bcrypt` and installing it back, but still getting that issue.
I also tried remove `bcrypt` from `package.json`, removed `node_modules` and then re-installed node, and works, but when install `bcrypt` back, it gives the same error.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using ARM as your processor by any chance? Have you tried to do: `npm --build-from-source install node-pre-gyp`?

Comment: `gyp` is a tool used by Node.js to compile modules written in C/C++. It is just a tool to aid compilation. Node does not ship with a C/C++ compiler by default. Do you have a C compiler and Python installed in your system? (weirdly gyp is written in Python)

Comment: Thanks for asking. I don’t have on this project. I’m installing stuff locally.

Answer (score 10):

After hours breaking my head on it, I tried using `npm i --save-dev @types/bcryptjs` instead and then worked.

The import can be used like this: `import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'`

Comment: I faced the same issue, I did the following to resolve it (my app is TypeScript + NextJs v14)
1- npm i --save-dev bcryptjs
2- npm i --save-dev @types/bcryptjs

Thank you

Comment: I did the same installed the js version for bcrypt and @types/bcryptjs, the error went away. I'm using TypeScript, not sure why it works. Appreciated if someone who is more knowledgeable could explain this to us.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue with my node_modules. Alternatively this can be used with react projects: `npm i bcryptjs-react` [link to npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs-react).

Comment: It worked as intended, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**I faced a similar issue and successfully resolved it with the following steps:**

If you have the existing bcrypt package installed, remove it:

```
npm rm bcrypt
```

Install bcryptjs as a development dependency:

```
npm i --save-dev bcryptjs
```

Additionally, install the type definitions for bcryptjs:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/bcryptjs
```

Following these steps resolved the issue for me.

Hopefully, it helps you too!

Comment: Thanks! This helped. I was stuck on it for hours.

Comment: Why would you install a package which isn't maintained for 7 years?